# Control a function (E.g send mail) from a users profile page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a profile page like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx4kg.png . In management I would like a option "Notify by mail" that would control my send_email functions in every application I want. As example I'm using django-messages and it sends private messages aswell as emails when you send a message. I would like for the user to be able to specify if he wants emails aswell when he gets a message.

messages/utils.py

```
def new_message_email(sender, instance, signal, 
        subject_prefix=_(u'New Message: %(subject)s'),
        template_name="messages/new_message.html",
        default_protocol=None,
        *args, **kwargs):
    """
    This function sends an email and is called via Django's signal framework.
    Optional arguments:
        ``template_name``: the template to use
        ``subject_prefix``: prefix for the email subject.
        ``default_protocol``: default protocol in site URL passed to template
    """
    if default_protocol is None:
        default_protocol = getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL', 'http')

    if 'created' in kwargs and kwargs['created']:
        try:
            current_domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
            subject = subject_prefix % {'subject': instance.subject}
            message = render_to_string(template_name, {
                'site_url': '%s://%s' % (default_protocol, current_domain),
                'message': instance,
            })
            if instance.recipient.email != "":
                send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                    [instance.recipient.email,])
        except Exception, e:
            #print e
            pass #fail silently
```

Apparently instance.recipient.email is the email for the recipient user. So my questions are: How do I go about creating an option in my profile management that can be used in my new_message_email to check if the user wants emails or not? My own thoughts are that I need to save a value in the database for the user and then check for that value in new_message_email function. How I do that isn't clear though. Do I create a new function in my userprofile/views.py and class in userprofile/forms.py? And have my userprofile/overview.html template change them? Some specifics and thoughts if this is the right approach would help alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to start off by [creating a user profile](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) so that you have a good way to store weather or not the user wants these emails sent to them.  This is done using the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting in your `settings.py`.

Once you have the data stored, you should be able to access it from `instance.recipient` (assuming that `instance.recipient` is a `User` object).  So you could change your code to:

```
if instance.recipient.get_profile().wants_emails and instance.recipient.email != "":
    send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        [instance.recipient.email,])
```

Done and done.

Comment: Done and done indeed! Added a BooleanField() to my profile and was able to use it exactly as described, thanks!